# Import User Installed Pip Package in Python Shell

Tags: python, linux, windows, shell, pip

Python is installed for the root/admin on the Windows desktop. So when I try to install using `pip install boto3`, I get the following error for not having write permissions to the below mentioned path.

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\program files\python37\Lib\site-packages\boto3'

As a workaround if I install the package only for the user using `pip install --user <Package-Name>`, I am able to install the package at `c:\users\kgoyal\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages\boto3\`.
Now while importing the same package inside the python shell, I get a ModuleNotFoundError.

How can I import a user installed package in the python shell and also get it to work with python scripts being executed by the python executable installed for the root/admin?

Comment: Install a virtual env or conda environment with the boto3 package in c:\users\kgoyal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the command using the "Run as Manager" option?

Comment: Run what as Manager ?

Also I don't have admin access on the machine.

Comment: I meant to open the Command Prompt as an administrator so that you can run commands that require administrative privileges, but if you don't have admin access it might be a problem. In this situation, I recommend you to install Anaconda Prompt in order to install python packages. You can use this link https://datatofish.com/how-to-install-python-package-in-anaconda/